# Graphs from which their minimal feedback vertex set has been removed

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading Vazirani's book "Approximation Algorithms". It is legally available online [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/Vijay.Vazirani/book.pdf).

On page 56 (74 in the pdf), I have a question regarding the claim at the bottom of the page:

> Clearly, $\sum_{i=1}^f comps (G-v_i)=f+t$.

Since the claim is purely graph-theoretic, I shall give a self-contained formulation below:

We are given a connected graph $G$ and a minimal [feedback vertex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set) $F=\{v_1,\dots,v_f\}$. We delete $F$ from $G$ and then partition the obtained connected components into two types:

1. Denote by $t$ the number of components whose edges are incident to only one of the vertices of $F$.
2. Denote by $k-t$ the number of components whose edges are incident to two or more vertices of $F$.

Lastly, $comps$(H) denotes the number of connected components in a graph $H$.

It follows that $\sum_{i=1}^f comps (G-v_i)=f+t$, but all of my (na?ve) attempts to justify that have failed.

**Progress update**:

i) Here is how I tried approaching this problem:

Obviously, each component of type 1 is present as an isolated component in exactly one graph $G-v_i$, for some $v_i\in F$. Thus when we sum over $comps(G-v_i)$, we'll encounter all $t$ components of this type.

To finish the proof of the claim, it would've been nice (and enough) if we could show that in each graph $G-v_i$, apart from the type 1 components associated with it, there is *only* one connected component (i.e. the component which is the union of all type 2 components, and also of $F-v_i$). That's where I got stuck.

ii) For an example of why minimality of $F$ is essential, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Y86.png) is a counterexample.

iii) This is not mentioned in the book (I'm not sure whether on purpose or not), but the claim is false if $|F|=1$. To see this, notice that $G\setminus F=G-v_1$. Thus $comps(G-v_1)$ (which is the only summand in the LHS) is equal to $t$, by definition of $t$. This is not equal to the RHS, which is $1+t$.

Intuitively, I'd say that the claim is true in all other cases (i.e. if $|F|\neq1$).

Comment: @NaïveSet: While your remark about minimality might be true, editing the post is not the correct and polite approach. It is better to signal the mistake to the OP in a comment and let him fix his own question.

Comment: @AlexM.: I agree, but in this case it has been done with the acknowledgement of the OP.